How do I get a type safe function return value in this case?
In the below code example I would like my IDE to accept mySap.rootValues[0].test2 and mySap.rootValues[1].test4 as valid. Right now, it doesn't, because rootValues[0] and rootValues[1] are of type TestRootOutput | TestRootOutput2.
type RootFunction<T, U> = (input: T) => U;

type Root<T, U> = {
  value: U;
};


const root = <T, U>(rootFn: RootFunction<T, U>): ((initialValue: T) => Root<T, U>) => {
  return initialInput => {
    let _value: U = rootFn(initialInput);

    return {
      get value() {
        return _value;
      },
    };
  };
};

interface TestRootInput {
  test: string;
}

interface TestRootOutput {
  test2: string;
}

interface TestRootInput2 {
  test3: string;
}

interface TestRootOutput2 {
  test4: string;
}

const testRoot = root<TestRootInput, TestRootOutput>(input => {
  return {test2: input.test};
});

const testRoot2 = root<TestRootInput2, TestRootOutput2>(input => {
  return {test4: input.test3};
});


type BranchSap = {roots: Root<any, any>[]};

const sap = <T extends BranchSap>(sap: T) => {
  const roots = sap.roots;

  return {
    rootValues: roots.map((root) => root.value as any as T['roots'][number]['value']),
  };
};
const mySap = sap({roots: [testRoot({test: 'hi'}), testRoot2({test3: 'hi2'})]});

// should be valid
console.log(mySap.rootValues[0].test2)

// should be valid
console.log(mySap.rootValues[1].test4)


@jcalz thank you for your comment. I edited a code sample below the original post.

@jcalz thank you again, I'm kind of new in asking questions here. I edited the original post. I hope this way it's explained better and you can copy it into your own IDE easily. I edited down the original code.

I'm sorry, there was another typo. fixed.

Does this approach meet your needs? If so I'll write up an answer explaining (but please do [edit] to change the unconventional K to the conventional U; see comment above). If not, what am I missing?

Thank you, I edited the orignal post. When I copy your approach into TS playground, the suggestions .test2 and .test4 work. However, when I try  to run the code there (also tried in my IDE), I get sap is not defined, or sap is not a function. I figure this is because of declare? It is supposed to transpile to an actual Javascript function.

Aren't you asking about the typings? You can surely implement the function however you want and use as any as like you're doing now. The JS part isn't really germane here unless you're asking "how can I convince the compiler that the implementation matches the call signature" but you're already using type assertions, so I'm confused.

see prev comment. I mean, feel free to do this but I'm not sure why that needs to be part of the question or answer per se.

I am asking how I can make a function that returns the values of the passed roots as an array in a strongly-typed way, so that my IDE gives proper suggestions when I access the rootValues at index X. In my original code, the return values were ambiguous. I am sorry, my skill level is such that I cannot really phrase it any better it seems. I am very grateful for your help here.

@jcalz, thank you, that last link is exactly what I needed! Now I need to understand somehow how and why it works haha

As I said, I'd write up an answer explaining. I'm not going to bother with the implementation though, since you already have that and it's not your problem.

Your sap() function has a return type of type {rootValues: Array<T['roots'][number]['value']>}. But T['roots'][number] is the  union of all the element types of the roots array, which completely loses track of which values are where in the array, and Array is an unordered homogeneous array type, and does not encode which types can be found at which index. So you've thrown away the information about the length and position of elements in T['roots'].
Instead you need rootValues to be a tuple type that depends on T['roots'].  First we want to make sure that T['roots'] is likely to be inferred as a tuple to begin with. For that we can make T a const type parameter:
const sap = <const T extends BranchSap>(sap: T): { ⋯ } => ⋯;

Then, we want to take T['roots'] and map it to a new tuple type.  That is, we make a mapped type to turn each element at index I of T['roots'] and turn it into T['roots'][I]['value']:
type RootVal<T extends Root<any, any>[]> =
  { [I in keyof T]: T[I]['value'] };

const sap = <const T extends BranchSap>(
  sap: T
): { rootValues: RootVal<T['roots']> } => ⋯;

Let's test it out from the caller's perspective:
const mySap = sap({
  roots: [
    testRoot({ test: 'hi' }),
    testRoot2({ test3: 'hi2' })
  ]
});

If you inspect with IntelliSense, you'll see that T is inferred as
{ readonly roots: [
     Root<TestRootInput, TestRootOutput>, 
     Root<TestRootInput2, TestRootOutput2>
   ];
}

due to the const type parameter. And therefore the output is of type
{ rootValues: [TestRootOutput, TestRootOutput2]; }

because that's what you get when you map the input tuple with RootVal.  And now mySap behaves exactly as you want:
mySap.rootValues[0].test2.toUpperCase(); // okay
mySap.rootValues[1].test4.toUpperCase(); // okay


Note that this has very little to do with the implementation of sap(). Mostly you will need to just use a type assertion to convince the compiler that the implementation satisfies the call signature:
const sap = <const T extends BranchSap>(
  sap: T
): { rootValues: RootVal<T['roots']> } => {
  const roots = sap.roots;
  return {
    rootValues: roots.map((root) => root.value),
  } as any; // <-- assert here or wherever you want
};

That's because the TypeScript typing for the map() array method doesn't produce a tuple type. Indeed it is impossible to have TypeScript do such a thing automatically, since the TypeScript type system lacks the necessary expressiveness to even represent it, see Mapping tuple-typed value to different tuple-typed value without casts.
In practice, most generic functions can't be verified by the compiler as safe, as it lacks the ability to analyze all but a few specific operations like indexing. And so you'll usually need a type assertion or the like.
Playground link to code

You're amazing. Thank you enormously for your great help and your insightful explanation!
